# Characteristic Function of Multivariate Normal

Tags: statistics, characteristic-functions

I am reading through the lecture notes of a statistics class, and it describes several steps on how to transfer the characteristic function of a standard normal into the characteristic function of a multivariate normal. Most of the steps I have no problem with, but there is one that seems slightly too big a leap. It says:
$$X\in N(0,I) \rightarrow \phi_X(t)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}t^Tt\right)$$ which is fair enough, but then immediately jumps to:
$$X\in N(\mu,\Sigma) \rightarrow \phi_X(t)=\exp\left(it^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}t^T\Sigma t\right)$$
I can see how this makes sense given the characteristic function of the normal distribution, but would this step not have to be substantiated a little bit more? Or is there some property that I am missing, that allows for this step to be easily made?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\sqrt{\Sigma}$ denote a positive-definite symmetric matrix that squares to $\Sigma$, so $\sqrt{\Sigma}^T\sqrt{\Sigma}=\Sigma$. (To prove one exists, consider a basis that diagonalises $\Sigma$, then square-root the eigenvalues.) Write $X=\mu+\sqrt{\Sigma}Z$ so$$\begin{align}\exp it^TX&=\exp(it^T\mu+i(\sqrt{\Sigma}t)^TZ)\\&=\exp(it^T\mu)\phi_Z(\sqrt{\Sigma}t)\\&=\exp\left(it^T\mu-\frac12t^T\sqrt{\Sigma}^T\sqrt{\Sigma}t\right)\\&=\exp\left(it^T\mu-\frac12t^T\Sigma t\right).\end{align}$$

Comment: Ah that is very smooth, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(\mu,\Sigma)$ then a matrix $A$ exists such that $X=\mu+AU$ where $U\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,I)$  and $\Sigma=AA^T$.

Then: $$\phi_X(t)=\mathbb Ee^{it^T(\mu+AU)}=e^{it^T\mu}\mathbb Ee^{it^TAU}=e^{it^T\mu}\phi_{U}(A^Tt)=e^{it^T\mu}e^{-\frac12t^TAA^Tt}=e^{it^T\mu-\frac12t^T\Sigma t}$$